# Drupal 8 \Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use | | dependency injection instead

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I used Drupal 8 and written a module.
in my form page I called.

```
\Drupal::service('library.discovery')->clearCachedDefinitions();
$cache = \Drupal::cache('discovery');
      $cache->delete('block_plugins');
```

It's worked, but I always see the warning.

> \Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use | | dependency
>   injection instead

I have the similar with File::load(), too.
I used:

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\file;
class BXBlock extends BlockBase {
public function build() {
...
$file = File::load($value);
...
}
}
```

Anybody can help me, please?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check how the dependency injection works in general in this documentation.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form

The parts that you need are:

Use statement -

```
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
```

Class property - here we are going to store the whole `\Drupal::service('current_user')` object.

```
 protected $account;
```

The `__construct` magic method. This is called upon instantiating the class.
The dependency injection bit here is providing all the data required in a later stage as input.

```
function __construct(AccountInterface $account) {
```

Built in method that  has a dependency injection
create(ContainerInterface $container)

```
return new static(
  // Load the service required to construct this class.
  $container->get('current_user')
);
```

Eventually we are using the whole construction like that:

```
$uid = $this->account->id();
```

where `$this->account` is the same like `\Drupal::service('current_user');`